# How to pass Spaces in Scenario name in Test Explorer using SpecFlow, NUnit, Gherkin

Tags: automation, cucumber, nunit, specflow, gherkin

i am working on a simple test case using SpecFlow and Gherkin Feature file i want to name my Scenario with spaces in Test Explorer

my Scenario name in Feature file

> Scenario: "Perform a Google search"

[image]

i want Here the name with spaces
is it possible, if yes please guide

Answer (score 0):

SpecFlow generates unit test classes based on the feature title and scenario names. These are real C# classes, so their names are constrained by the C# language.

What you want is not possible because Visual Studio Test Explorer is displaying the namespaces, classes and methods that are decorated with NUnit test attributes. Since namespace, method and class names in C# cannot contain spaces, you cannot have spaces appear in Test Explorer.

As an alternative, you can [group tests by Trait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer?view=vs-2022#group-and-filter-the-test-list). SpecFlow usually adds additional attributes to the test classes generated from your feature files that give you more human-readable names, although if I remember correctly these are not the scenario names. I think you can see the `FeatureTitle` trait, which gives you the title of the feature, but not the scenarios inside it.